# JQuery Creating Modal and Opening

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a  modal and display it when user click on the image.There are some methods like making modal invisible and after clicking somewhere JQuery makes it visible but i do not want to use these methods ,only want to create and display modal with JQuery.

How can i create it with JQuery dynamically?

Comment: why do you want to create if there are already ready ones to use?

Answer (score 0):

The emphasize in your question is to create a dialogue on click, and destroy as opposite to show and hide right. Either is easy.

```
<img class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" onclick="dynamicModal()"/> Click image
```

Here's a js portion

```
dynamicModal = function() {
     $("<div>Dinamically created</div>").dialog({
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        position: ['center', 'top'],
        show: 'blind',
        hide: 'blind',
        width: 400,
        dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
        buttons: {
            "Destroy": function() {
                $(this).dialog("destroy");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Finally a fiddle to try it out http://jsfiddle.net/pfL5LL06/5/

Notice that a div node is created on the fly  `$("<div>Dinamically created</div>")` and not bound to an existing element